# MSQL auditing with CLR integration

Tags: sql, audit

I'm dot.net developer, and i'm working a lot with MSQL. My current task is when some user executes select query on database, i should "catch" the query data. What do i mean is if select query is "select * from UsersTbl where UserID = 5", i have to get  '5'. Does somebody have any idea where to start???

Thanks a lot.

Dmitry

Comment: What is `MSQL`? Microsoft SQL Server I assume from mention of CLR? If so what version?

Answer (score 0):

You could extract each value that starts with an = 
But you might find a solution using MySQL Proxy... I've never used it so don't hold me to that :)